# WordPress: CSS gets messed up when changing permalink. Suspected Theme Conflict

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I have a wordpress site and I'm having trouble setting permalinks for one particular page.

I have a "Services" page with custom CSS. The problem is that the page only works when I set the permalink to anything but the name "Services". If I change the permalink the CSS is fine. I can literally change it to anything and even change the parent and the CSS works fine. But as soon as I set the parent as none and set the permalink to "Services" it redirects me to an "Archived Services" page with the wrong formatting.

I suspect that there is a conflict with my theme (Uncode Theme) as there might already be a Services page provided by the theme and its giving it more priority - but I can't seem to find it.

Is there anyway I can set the permalink to Services and NOT have the CSS change? I need the simpler permalink for better SEO.

Thanks.

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with permalink unless you have conditions when the file to load. Also you probably have custom post type services which have archive page. So as you can see you cant have PAGE and Archive with same slug. You can read more about here - https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ and https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/ . I would recommend contacting the theme author for help.